# How to find the probability of X=6, where X is the max of 3 6-sided dice

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm fairly certain the answer is $91/6^3$ (confirming it through a script),  but I'm not certain how to solve the problem in a mathematically sound way. I made an attempt that got to the right answer, but I'm not sure if what I did was logically correct:

So I know that there is only one way that you can get the outcome $\omega$ {666}

There is also the outcomes $\omega$ = {6BC, A6C, AB6} where A,B and C can be any number 1-5.

Lastly there are the outcomes $\omega$ = {66C, 6B6, A66}, where A, B and C are again any number 1-5.

The total outcomes that satisfy the $\omega :X(\omega)= 6$ is:
$$1 + 5*5*(3 choose 1) + 5 * (3 choose 2)= 91$$

and the total outcomes in $\omega$ is 6*6*6, so $P(X=6)= 91/6^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your number is right. For another way of computing, let us find the probability that the maximum is $\le 5$. That's the probability of getting three numbers that are $5$ or below.  The probability of that is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$.

So the probability the maximum is $6$ is $1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3$.

**Remark:** Here is a more complicated problem. What is the probability that the maximum is $5$? This happens if they are all $\le 5$. but not all $\le 4$. The probability of this is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^3$.